# understanding ros clock

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i don't understand the clock's value, why i get: time.sec =1412932920?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194683/understanding-ros-clock/) by [idavico](https://answers.ros.org/users/20379/idavico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The time is represented in [Unix epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which represents the number of seconds elapsed since Thursday, 1 January 1970.

Documentation for the clock is at http://wiki.ros.org/Clock

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3